# Rotate a Collection in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm not sure if "rotate" is the best word in the programming word for explain what I need but I will try.

I have this collection:

```
^ Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2341 ▼
  #items: array:187 [▼
    1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1506 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▼
        0 => "ulbPln_idPrd"
        1 => "Decimal"
        2 => "<No value>"
        3 => "<No value>"
      ]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
    2 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2280 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▼
        0 => "idCanDiag"
        1 => "Decimal"
        2 => "<No value>"
        3 => "<No value>"
      ]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
```

As you can see is a 187 element collection, and each rows has 4 items.

What I need is to "rotate" the collection and get a 4 array of 187 items

```
    ^ Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2341 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1506 ▼
      #items: array:187 [▼
        0 => "ulbPln_idPrd"
        1 => "idCanDiag"
      ...
      ]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
    2 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2280 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▼
        0 => "Decimal"
        1 => "Decimal"
      ...
      ]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
```

I ask this, cause some months ago I read something about a helper in the laravel documentation to do this, but now I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to transpose a matrix.

[image: Transpose a matrix]

This can be easily done thanks to `data_set` and `data_get` helpers

Basically, We want

```php
$A = collect([
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f']
]);
```

to become

```php
$B = collect([
    ['a', 'd'],
    ['b', 'e'],
    ['c', 'f']
]);
```

This should work.

```php
$B = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($A->first()); $i++)
    for ($j = 0; $j < $A->count(); $j++)
        data_set($B, "$i.$j", data_get($A, "$j.$i"));

$B = collect($B);
```

The limitations are the following:

1. No associative arrays.
2. It's assuming every row has the same amount of elements.

This is simple enough you could make it a `Collection` macro.

```php
# AppServiceProvider class
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

public function boot()
{
    Collection::macro('transpose', function () {
        // maybe add some error checking
        $new = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->first()); $i++)
            for ($j = 0; $j < $this->count(); $j++)
                data_set($new, "$i.$j", data_get($this, "$j.$i"));

        return collect($new);
    });
}
```

And then you could call it freely everywhere else.

```php
$transposed = $yourCollection->transpose();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find this exact functionality (and a lot more) with the [Spatie Collection Macros Package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-collection-macros) for Laravel

Specifically [the transpose macro](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-collection-macros/blob/main/src/Macros/Transpose.php) along with which you can find tests for, to help create confidence that the code works.

I have no link to Spatie, but I use this transform macro a lot in projects I maintain.